# While statement is heroku discord bot stops working after a while

Tags: python, heroku, while-loop, discord.py

I made my first discord bot and what it does is it listens for a command called `+purge` and purges all the messages in the channel it was executed in.

However, like my other friends' bot, the bot became dysfunctional. This may be Heroku, but I doubt it? I might need a break statement, but not sure about it. I am also trying to have this run on multiple servers so I want the boolean variables to have server ids for each name of them.

By not working I mean it won't delete the messages anymore, and somewhat glitch out when you spam messages after you run the command I think. It might have something to do with the `isActive` variable.

```
isActive = False

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@has_role("Guild Master")
async def purge(ctx):
    global isActive
    isActive = not isActive
    if isActive:
        while isActive:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=999)
```

Answer (score 0):

- `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=999)` does not need to be put in a while loop since the function already uses its own loop to delete
- Since you declared the boolean `isActive` as global, the boolean's state saves outside the scope, resulting in the function running every other time it is called
- You can bin the concept of an `isActive` boolean since the code underneath your function automatically becomes active after it is called
- The function should, in your case, only be a couple lines (and still work fine in any guild):

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@has_role("Guild Master")
async def purge(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=999)
```

EDIT: If we want to delete every message sent in a channel, we can use an `on_message` listener, like so:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel == noMessageChannel:
         await message.delete()
```

Comment: Hey! I am making this command to have it be a toggle, to always purge the commands every second, not do it once. That is why I made the while loop. If you still understand what I am trying to do, I tried out the code and looked at your explanation and it only purged once haha. I think the session of the command expires somehow and the while loop will stop. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want every message sent in a channel to constantly be deleted, an on_message listener would be the way to go. I'll edit my answer to include an example

Comment: What would I put for the noMessageChannel variable? How would I get this listener decorator do be triggered by a command?

Comment: The variable `noMessageChannel` would be a channel object. To get a channel object, you could use `bot.get_channel(id)` where `id` is an int representing a channel's ID. You can toggle it on and off by creating a command that edits a boolean variable. That variable can dictate whether the listener should delete messages or not with a simple if statement. If something still isn't clear, ask away!